# How to return to same place in for loop with multiple windows in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, architecture, user-input, delegation, nsnotification

I have a for loop editing an array of model objects, some of which require user input and some of which do not. I would like to be able to open a second window as needed to display multiple choices to the user, receive the user's selection, close the second window, and then return to the place I was in the original loop. In AppleScript, this could be done simply with a "choose from list" dialog. But I haven't figured out how to do it in Cocoa since the NSNotificationCenter architecture requires me to process the second window's response in a different selector. Thus the loop is broken and I can't process the rest of the array. I also tried doing it with delegation to no avail. Are panels and alerts the only way to do this?

Comment: Correct. You would not use a loop in this case. Make a temporary array of things you need to prompt the user for.  After the user input, remove that item from the array and ask the for the next input.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it now.